# Show loading with minimum delay each time when using React Router v6 Link

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-router

Use React and Router v6

App.tsx:

```
const Page1 = lazy(() => pMinDelay(import('./views/Page1'), 500))
const Page2 = lazy(() => pMinDelay(import('./views/Page2'), 500))

return (
      <Suspense fallback={<Loading/>}>
          <Routes>
            <Route path='/page1' element={<Page1/>}/>
            <Route path='/page2' element={<Page2/>}/>
```

Navigation:

```
<Link to='/page1'>Page 1</Link>
<Link to='/page2'>Page 2</Link>
```

When visit URL /page1 first time, loading with 0.5s works ok, when navigate again - loading and delay not working.

I need loading spinner with minimum delay each time when navigate using /page1 and /page2.

So, and <Link reloadDocument ..> not fit for my app, because all app will be refresh.

Comment: What is `pMinDelay` and why do you think the component will be lazy loaded a second time? See [mcve]. Perhaps you should enforce the delayed navigation from the link instead of the route loading. What is the purpose of delaying/slowing your app's navigation actions though?

Comment: @DrewReese thank you for response. pMinDelay are used for make simulate timeout for delay (https://www.npmjs.com/package/p-min-delay). I want show my loading spinner before show view and this 0.5s delay fix spinner flashing problem.

Comment: I don't know what "spinner flashing problem" is, but it seems you could also just handle this in the routed components as well, displaying whatever 0.5s loading indicator you need/want when the components mount.

Answer (score 0):

You successfully split page 1 and page 2 from your main bundle and it will be loaded when needed once and not twice.

If you want to wait some moment anyway, it seems to be better to make a custom hook like useTimeout with your component. because you can do more things while waiting.